# How to make button variable visible within an onClick event?

Tags: android, button, scope, switch-statement

I wanted to have two seperate button in one onClick event by using a switch statement but when I did this I got these errors relating to the `jPBtn` and `vFBtn` variables:

`vfBtn cannot be resolved or is not a field`

`jpBtn cannot be resolved or is not a field`

So I know what this means is that the button variables can't be seen by the click event but the question I'm wondering is why they are not visible as I have declared them in onCreate and set them to the listener? Should I be re declaring them again somewhere else?

This is the class for reference:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements android.view.View.OnClickListener {

    Button jpBtn,vfBtn;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        jpBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.JourneyPlanBtn);
        jpBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

        vfBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.FindCarBtn);
        vfBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.jpBtn:
             //DO something
            Intent intent = new Intent(null, JourneyPlanner.class);
            startActivity(intent);  
        break;
        case R.id.vfBtn:
             //DO something
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(null, VechicleFinderMain.class);
            startActivity(intent);  
        break;

    }

        Intent intent = new Intent(null, JourneyPlanner.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

}
```

Comment: Are you importing the R file properly?

Comment: if you have button id with same names in your xml layout try to save all your files

Comment: no I have different name in class and xml,also I tried save,clean..but still getting the error.Is it an error in my code?

Comment: could you post your xml layout ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it like this. See the case statements.

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.JourneyPlanBtn:
             //DO something
            Intent intent = new Intent(null, JourneyPlanner.class);
            startActivity(intent);  
        break;
        case R.id.FindCarBtn:
             //DO something
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(null, VechicleFinderMain.class);
            startActivity(intent);  
        break;

    }
```

Comment: Simple just reference the xml variables not the class variables,should have remembered that,thanks